# Do I need to configure interoperability between Conda and pip for each new environment?

Tags: pip, anaconda, conda

From Conda 4.6 onwards, it is possible to configure Conda to directly install PyPi packages using pip (https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/). Specifically, you need to manually enable it via `conda config --set pip_interop_enabled True`

I don't know how to check Conda's existing configurations, so I can't tell if this setting persists globally across environments or if I need to manually enable it every time I create a new environment. Any ideas?

I hardly see anyone mention this feature so far, which I guess is understandable considering that official article has been out for only about 3 months. So far, I've only found one answer in one SO question referencing this feature, and that's only mentioning that it exists.

Answer (score 6):

Be aware that mixing Conda and Pip is still generally discouraged, despite the existence of this experimental feature. I strongly recommend continuing to follow the best practices suggested in "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)".

The description "*to configure Conda to directly install PyPI packages using pip*" isn't so accurate. Instead, the feature is to enable Conda to consider the presence of PyPI-installed packages when attempting to resolve dependencies. It does not enable Conda to install things using `pip`. It has more to do with preventing Conda from blindly clobbering PyPI packages when they are present.

It should be noted that [using an env YAML](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually) to create (`conda env create -f env.yaml`) or update (`conda env update -f env.yaml`) an env does already support using `pip` - with or without this feature enabled.

As for settings, you can always check all settings with `conda config --show`.  Whenever you use `conda config --set` it defaults to making a global change. If you want to set a configuration variable only for a specific env, then you must activate the env and include `--env` flag when running `conda config --set`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I only use pip when the packages I need are missing from conda, not maintained or otherwise not usable for any reason. So in those cases there is definitely no "conda version" of the packages I'll be installing from PyPi. hyperas and hyperopt are two immediate examples that come to mind.

Comment: It's crazy to me that conda would install pip in all of your environments and then blissfully ignore any pip-installed packages in the environment.  I'm sure this has been a source negative surprise for plenty of folks.

Comment: @Robert Well, technically it recognizes they are there (e.g., `conda list` shows them), but Conda doesn't factor them into the solver by default. It's further aggravated by the fact that not all PyPI package names match Conda ones, so it's not trivial to integrate.

Comment: Yeah I'm just wondering why `pip_interop_enabled=False` is the default.  What dragons are waiting for us when we set this to True?

Comment: @Robert I think the biggest worry is the assumption that the build of a package on PyPI is identical to the build on Conda. An example of a potential problem is that some Python packages are wrappers for non-Python software/shared libraries. Conda builds of such packages will explicitly declare such dependencies and ensure they get installed. This isn't always the case with PyPI builds. So, if a wrapper  package is already installed via PyPI and satisfies a dependency in a Conda solve, there could be missing sub-dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

> How to check Conda's existing configurations:

`conda config --show`

---

While @merv's answer provides more depth, the OP actually asked the simple question above, so I thought I would answer it.

`conda config --show` will list *all* configurations, including whether or not `pip_interop_enabled` is `True` or `False`.